# Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of null

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I have strange issue showed up recently on my script and not sure what causes this issue to happen. It is popping up on Chrome browser mainly and I guess this function **'offsetHeight'** is either deprecated or invalid. 
here is the full code:

```
    var Rep_Templates = {

    // array of pre-defined reasons
    answers: null,

    // popup container
    context_menu: null,
    // popup copntiner height
    menu_height: 0,
    error_msg: null,

    // ajax form and its param values
    pseudoform: null,
    url: null,
    postid: 0,

    // information phrases to display to user
    thanks_phrase: '',
    description_msg: '',

    timer_id: null,


    /**
     * inits the popup
     * @param answers array of pre-defined reasons
     * @param error_msg to display in case of empty message
     * @param url of current page
     * @param thanks_phrase diaplyed after successful submission
     */
    init: function(answers, url, phrases) {
        if (AJAX_Compatible)
        {
            this.answers = answers;
            this.error_msg = phrases['error'];
            this.thanks_phrase = phrases['thanks'];
            this.description_msg = phrases['description'];

            this.context_menu = new YAHOO.widget.Menu("rep_tmpl_popup",
                                                          {clicktohide: false,
                                                           effect: {
                                                             effect: YAHOO.widget.ContainerEffect.FADE,
                                                             duration: 0.25
                                                          }});
            // Fix for IE7 z-index bug
            if (YAHOO.env.ua.ie && YAHOO.env.ua.ie < 8)
            {
                this.context_menu.cfg.setProperty("position", "dynamic");
                this.context_menu.cfg.setProperty("iframe", true);
                this.context_menu.cfg.setProperty("zindex", 10100);
            }
            this.context_menu.render(document.body);

            var menu_object = fetch_object("rep_tmpl_menu_inner");
            this.menu_height = menu_object.offsetHeight;


            var links = YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementsByClassName("report", "a", document.body);
            for ( var i = 0; i < links .length; i++ ) {
                var index = links[i].href.indexOf("p=");
                if (index > 0)
                {
                    var postid = links[i].href.substr(index+2);
                    YAHOO.util.Event.on(links[i], "click", this.show_popup, postid);
                }
            }


            this.pseudoform = new vB_Hidden_Form('ajax.php');
            this.pseudoform.add_variable('ajax', 1);
            this.pseudoform.add_variable('s', fetch_sessionhash());
            this.pseudoform.add_variable('securitytoken', SECURITYTOKEN);
            this.pseudoform.add_variable('do', 'email_report');
            this.url = url;
        }
    },

    /**
     * inserts pre-defined reason into textarea
     * @param id of selected reason
     */
    set_answer: function(id) {
        var textarea = fetch_object('rep_tmpl_message');
        textarea.value = '';
        if (id > 0 && id <= this.answers.length)
        {
            textarea.value = this.answers[id-1];

            var error_msg = fetch_object('rep_tmpl_error');
            error_msg.innerHTML = "";
        }
    },

    /**
     * show popup to the user
     * @param event click event
     * @param postid id of the post
     */
    show_popup: function(event,postid) {
        Rep_Templates.reset_data();
        YAHOO.util.Event.stopEvent(event);
        var elem = event.srcElement? event.srcElement : event.target;
        Rep_Templates.postid = postid;
        var xy = [0,0];

        xy[0] = YAHOO.util.Dom.getX(elem) + 25;
        xy[1] = YAHOO.util.Dom.getY(elem) - Rep_Templates.menu_height;

        if (xy[1] < 0)
        {
            xy[1] = 0;
        }
        Rep_Templates.context_menu.moveTo(xy[0],xy[1]);
        Rep_Templates.context_menu.show();

        fetch_object('rep_tmpl_message').focus();
        YAHOO.util.Event.on(document.body, "click", Rep_Templates.hide_menu);
    },

    /**
     * hides the menu when users click Hide button or click outside of the  popup. Resets data
     * @param optional event. If specified, then user clicked outside.  
     */
    hide_menu: function(event) {
        var is_inside = false;
        if (event)
        {
            // check if click was inside or outside popup
            var obj = event.srcElement? event.srcElement : event.target;
            do {
                if (obj.id == 'rep_tmpl_popup') {
                     is_inside = true;
                    break;
                }
            } while (obj = obj.parentNode);

            if (!is_inside)
            {
                 YAHOO.util.Event.removeListener(document.body, "click", Rep_Templates.hide_menu);
            }
        }

        if (!event || !is_inside)
        {
            Rep_Templates.context_menu.hide();
            Rep_Templates.postid = 0;
        }
    },

    /**
     * reset all fields with default values
     */
    reset_data: function() {
        var error_msg = fetch_object('rep_tmpl_error');
        error_msg.innerHTML = "";

        var phrase = fetch_object('rep_tmpl_phrase');
        phrase.innerHTML = this.description_msg;
        YAHOO.util.Dom.removeClass(phrase, 'rep_tmpl_thanks_message');

        var button = fetch_object('rep_tmpl_submit');
        YAHOO.util.Dom.removeClass(button, 'disabled');
        button.disabled = false;

        var image = fetch_object('rep_tmpl_progress');
        image.style.display = 'none';
    },

    /**
     * sends AJAX request
     * @param event click event
     */
    send_data: function(event) {

        var textarea = fetch_object('rep_tmpl_message');
        if (textarea && textarea.value.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '') != '')
        {
            this.pseudoform.add_variable('postid', this.postid);
            this.pseudoform.add_variable('url',this.url + "&p="+ this.postid + "#post" + this.postid);

            var button = event.srcElement? event.srcElement : event.target;
            button.disabled = true;

            YAHOO.util.Dom.addClass(button, 'disabled');

            var image = fetch_object('rep_tmpl_progress');
            image.style.display = '';

            YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest("POST", 'ajax.php', {
                success: this.handle_ajax_response,
                failure: vBulletin_AJAX_Error_Handler,
                timeout: vB_Default_Timeout,
                scope: this
            }, this.pseudoform.build_query_string() + '&reason=' + textarea.value);
        }
        else
        {
            var error_msg = fetch_object('rep_tmpl_error');
            error_msg.innerHTML = this.error_msg;
        }
        return false;
    },

    /**
     * handles AJAX request
     * @param ajax data returned
     */
    handle_ajax_response: function(ajax) {
        if (ajax.responseXML)
        {
            // check for error first
            var error = ajax.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('error');
            if (error.length)
            {
                this.reset_data();
                var error_msg = fetch_object('rep_tmpl_error');
                error_msg.innerHTML = error[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            }
            else
            {
                var result = ajax.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('result');
                if (result.length)
                {
                    var image = fetch_object('rep_tmpl_progress');
                    image.style.display = 'none';

                    var phrase = fetch_object('rep_tmpl_phrase');
                    phrase.innerHTML = this.thanks_phrase;
                    YAHOO.util.Dom.addClass(phrase, 'rep_tmpl_thanks_message');

                    this.timer_id = setTimeout('Rep_Templates.handle_timer_expiration()',1000);
                }
            }
        }
    },

    /**
     * hides popup on timer expiration
     */
    handle_timer_expiration: function() {
        clearTimeout(this.timer_id);
        this.hide_menu();
    }
}
```

any idea how to solve this issue!!

Thanks

Comment: What is the function `fetch_object`?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the object `menu_object` is null. My guess is that the element that you are looking for does not exist. Check out your element and make sure that it has the correct identifier (class or id) to match  `fetch_object("rep_tmpl_menu_inner")`

Comment: Thanks, mate. This is something I've never thought of. possibly matching id or class as you mentioned. :)